# How to echo part of an Array with an API?

Tags: php

I am obvious very new to PHP (and programming). I use a system for invoicing customers. In that system I can create custom fields for customers for extra information.

When the customers login, I want them to be able to see some extra information.

I have tried to connect to the MySQL database directly, but that results in showing the first row of the custum field to every client. The client should obviously only see the custom field with there own information.

Now I found some API examples and I can retrieve al data from the logged-in customer. I tried a lot of examples and searched on php.net but all examples I found seems for static array data (I hope I say that right:)).

```
<?php

echo ('<pre>');

$api = new HostFactAPI();

$debtorParams = array(
                'Identifier'    => '1'
);

$response = $api->sendRequest('debtor', 'show', $debtorParams);

print_r_pre($response);

?>
```

This is the result I get:

```
Array
(
[controller] => debtor
[action] => show
[status] => success
[date] => 2019-04-10T10:24:09+02:00
[debtor] => Array
    (
        [Identifier] => 144
        [DebtorCode] => 208410
        [CompanyName] => Test
        [CompanyNumber] => 
        [LegalForm] => ANDERS
        [TaxNumber] => 
        [Sex] => m
        [Initials] => T
        [SurName] => Testsurname
        [Address] => Testaddress
        [Groups] => Array
            (
            )

        [Created] => 2019-01-11 15:12:57
        [Modified] => 2019-04-10 08:39:20
        [CustomFields] => Array
            (
                [CustomFieldtestdata] => test
            )
# and more but not important I think
```

With this I get to retrieve the CompanyName:

```
echo ($account->CompanyName) ? normalize($account->CompanyName) . '<br />' : '';
```

But I tried everything that I possibly could come up with to get the data from [CustomFieldtestdata], but I cannot get it done. Maybe because no function(?) exists yet for this field?

I hope someone can put me in the right direction.

Comment: If you need to show customer specified info, you can query just only the info you need with conditional logic if it's only on selected customer, use session value to store customer id

Comment: what did you try so far? I think you can get it this way: `echo ($account->CustomFields->CustomFieldtestdata) ? normalize($account->CustomFields->CustomFieldtestdata) . '<br />' : '';`

Comment: Where is `$account` declared?

Comment: why not `$response['debtor']['CompanyName']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $response['debtor']['customFields']['CustomFieldtestdata'];
```

Comment: Great Donny, that works! Thanks a lot! Did not think it was that "easy" (still hard if you don`t know;))

Comment: Keep coding and soon you'll get the hang of it ^_^